# How to generate an array of random numbers without any duplicates (in Java)?

Tags: java

Below is my attempt to populate an array with randomly generated numbers without producing any duplicates. Yet, I am still getting duplicates. Where am I going wrong?

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x = 6;
int[] selectionsIndex = new int[x];
String[] pool = {"Tom", "Ralph", "Sam", "Craig", "Fred", "Bob", "Tess", "Kayla", "Nina"}; // = 9

for(int i = 0; i < selectionsIndex.length; i++){
    // Initial random
    selectionsIndex[i] = rnd.nextInt(pool.length);

    // Check whether generated number matches any previously generated numbers
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        // Match, so generate a new number and restart check
        if(selectionsIndex[i] == selectionsIndex[j]){
            selectionsIndex[i] = rnd.nextInt(pool.length);
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what I am guessing you want this array, a more common strategy is to populate your array of length N with the numbers from 0 to N-1 in order, then compute a permutation of that array to scramble the numbers in it.  Pick a number of iterations (M), then for that many times, pick two elements of the array at random and swap them.  Faster than generating random numbers until you get all N of them...

Comment: @moilejter AFAIK, this kind of shuffle (like Hindu shuffle) is very slow for a well-distributed shuffle, generating a random number from a barrel (like picking random card in the pile of card) is kindly better.

Comment: Hey @R.Overbeck do mark the answer as correct by clicking on V type tick mark looking button next to the answer, this helps future readers of this question and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Set` in Java to add the random numbers you have generated, this would get you the numbers and no numbers would be duplicates.

In code it may look something like this:

```java
Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>();
while (uniques.size()<10){
    uniques.add(rand.nextInt(11));
}
for (Integer i : uniques){
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

Some more information about Sets:

- Set is an interface which extends Collection. It is an unordered collection of objects in which duplicate values cannot be stored.
- Basically, Set is implemented by HashSet, LinkedHashSet or TreeSet (sorted representation).
- Set has various methods to add, remove clear, size, etc to enhance the usage of this interface

[Know and read more about Sets here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJvra7ofHeAhXCyqQKHQxLA7wQFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FSet.html&usg=AOvVaw1V3JBFijMWsNiebSIG00yp).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of the code

```
if(selectionsIndex[i] == selectionsIndex[j]){
            selectionsIndex[i] = rnd.nextInt(pool.length);
            j = 0;
        }
```

At first glimpse your code looks absolutely fine but the devil is in the details, here's the short answer, just do this

`j =-1` instead of `j=0`

and it'll work fine

**The Devil**

You see, the `for` loop increments first and then proceeds except at the initialization step, hence when you do `j=0` you expect the checking to start from `0` but instead it starts from `1` because `j` gets incremented and hence the `0th` index is not checked at all.

That's why you see repetition with the `0th` index and some other index only and not with any other pairs of indices.